# MongoDB Windows Service stop working again and again

Tags: php, mongodb, windows-7-x64

Can somebody pleas help me to figure out MongoDb Service corruption on windows 7. 
whenever I reinstalled the service and all using logs correct syntax etc it worked perfectly at that time.

When I restarted my sytem after each reinstall of mongodB service it get stopped working. Don't know what is the issue in service after system restart it stops working with following error in log file

```
Unable to check for journal files due to: boost::filesystem::basic_directory_iterator     constructor: The system cannot find the path specified: "f:\server\mongodb\mongodb-win32-i386-2.2.0\data\db\journal"
```

Everything all paths I configured Like below:

```
mongod.exe --install --config f:\server\mongodb\mongodb-win32-i386-2.2.0\conf\mongodb.conf --logpath f:\server\mongodb\mongodb-win32-i386-2.2.0\logs\mongodb.log
```

Service stops working only after system restart.

Comment: What are the contents of your f:\server\mongodb\mongodb-win32-i386-2.2.0\conf\mongodb.conf file?  Do you have a f:\server\mongodb\mongodb-win32-i386-2.2.0\data\db directory, and is it writable by the account that the mongod.exe Windows service is running in?

Comment: @Tad Marshall! Hi Sorry I was gone someehere. Yes I have f:\server\mongodb\mongodb-win32-i386-2.2.0\data\db and is writeable. Here is the link for log file on pastebin [link](http://pastebin.com/1s48e2PY). Please help me to figure this out. I don't know how to deal with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to make sure that:
1. There is a folder c:\data\db.
2. There was not an unexpected shutdown of your computer.

I solved such a problem by deleting all from c:\data\db :)

Comment: Actually Accidental Shutdowns were the key issue for me. :| but I fixed it. Sorry for late comment.